# IE8 Compatibility mode issue

Tags: css, jsp, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser

I have created one jsp page that page is working fine across the all browser.when i rendered that page in IE8 browser it's working fine.But problem is when i select

Browser Mode-IE8 Compatibility View than corresponding

Document Mode- IE7 Standards will be selected automatically.

then my jsp page giving a lot alignment issue.But when i select again

Document Mode- IE8 Standards than my page working fine..

How i can control this thing Is there any way to setting because i can change again again the document mode..i want Document Mode will fix IE8 Standard..

Please provide the solution how i can handle this issue...

Comment: Have you included a <!DOCTYPE> at the top of the pages in question?

Comment: yes i have included ..right now i am using this ..<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Comment: please give me some solution so that i can fix that issue

Comment: See my answer below :) hopefully that should fix it!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing the DOCTYPE to:

`<DOCTYPE html>`

And then try adding this meta tag into the `<head>` of your document:

`<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>`

This meta tag should force IE into standards mode, you can find more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258/whats-the-difference-if-meta-http-equiv-x-ua-compatible-content-ie-edge-e).

You should end up with something that looks like:

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Page Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Content</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanx for your reply ..but i need your one clarification..if my browser by default set IE 8 Compatibility mode and also  i can't change standard mode manually in all 100 system..in that case it convert automatically compatibility mode to standard mode..

Comment: It should hopefully yes, unless the user sets it to compatability mode after the page has loaded.

Comment: Although I'm not 100% sure though, and I don't currently have access to machines for testing this, sorry.

Comment: Thanx man for your valuable feedback ..i really appreciate for that ..cheers..:)

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of assistance :)

Comment: Warning: this tag needs to be placed before all other elements (except for the title element and other meta elements)